# Can I make dua for the past?

Tags: dua, destiny

I don't know if this makes sense but: What if I desperately pray and say "*O Allah!*, please make sure that my laptop wasn't hacked at that time (in the past)". As Allah knows everything about our future including our *duas*, therefore, at that time in the past for which I am praying now, He knew that I will make a *dua*, right? Allah is capable of anything and everything.

So, can I make *dua* for the past?

Comment: You still need to clear. Didn't you know that your computer was hacked?

Comment: I'm not to sure if it was certainly hacked

Comment: why not ask Allah: `Oh God, please make sure whatever happened to my laptop doesn't cause me any harm `

Comment: whatever is gone, is gone. it cannot be changed. it happened because Allah willed it to happe in the way it happened. so be patient on whatever has passed, and worry about present and future.

Comment: similar question : http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/can-allah-change-the-past

Comment: This is technically what is called *طول الامل* meaning 'wishes that never come true or are too difficult'. And they are not recommended in Islam

Comment: another similar question : http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4184/can-god-allah-%d8%b3%d8%a8%d8%ad%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%87-%d9%88-%d8%aa%d8%b9%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%89-change-the-past

Comment: The Messenger of Allah ﷺ repeated three times, “Those who search deeply for confusing questions have perished.” (Muslim)

Comment: On a side note, please be aware of the following:
It's Almighty Allah you are communicating with here, not your friend. Your level of thinking when you make dua should be on much higher and deeper level when you're communicating with him through dua. As @user2724 mentioned, how about such a dua and reciting surah al-falaq a few times

Answer (score 0):

Yes because at that time he knew that you were going to make this Dua in the future so he could have fixed your problem before you made the Dua. Because he knew you were going to make it.

Comment: But it didn't seem to work if your computer was hacked. If you pray now that it not be hacked, is that supposed to change the past?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that God can do everything, but it doesn't mean that he definitely do what ask him. Occasionally he comes true your wishes, sometimes he does not. It could be related to his realization about your interest..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because Allah is free of the bounds of time as He is the Creator of time. His existence is not one like ours.

لَيْسَ كَمِثْلِهِ شَيْءٌ وَهُوَ السَّمِيعُ الْبَصِير

(Al-Shura:11)

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because Allah created time.

But instead of saying, "O Allah!, please make sure that my laptop wasn't hacked at that time (in the past)" say, "O Allah, remove the damages which was caused by hacker and make everything like it was never hacked."

Answer (score -1):

i think it is ok.

because , i think, there are lots of almost similar and different, of different level of difference, copies of our world. it is named multiverse theory.

and, if so, what happens when you make dua and it allah helps you? you get/walk into the future branch of your world which you wanted. and if you ask for past and allah helps you, it also can be similar way, if you are now watching the world and this your local part of the world, felt by you, is similar in many-many different versions of world, and allah can make it so that you will get into one of them which is good. and in both cases, whether it is past or future, the bad branches/threads of world also exist.

but since you do not know in which world you are, you should plan your future behavior for several possible versions (of the what happened). and if you can know out more clearly what happened, then you can plan/behave for that case. (and your copies in other "parallel" worlds, who know out more clearly that their past is other, should behave appropriately, but that should not bother the you in this your world any more).

before effect of something happened in past reaches you, it is like future for you. if you have signs of that event which are not strong, apparent, they can still appear as wrong and be reinterpreted.

Comment: i have seen a film where multiverse was shown as universes in bubbles inside a universe, but i mean not that, i mean separate universes.

Comment: there is a hadith that rejects multiworld: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27693/where-is-source-of-this-hadith-nawawi-what-has-befallen-you-was-not-going

Comment: no, it does not reject it, because, indeed, in every one of the worlds there maybe only one concrete history, but there maybe lot of slightly different copies of world and history, and as i said here, we may not know in which we are.

Comment: after 1-2 weeks after i have written this i have felt, was afraid that i really was moved to another world, or, i died in many variants of the worlds, and have continued to live only in few amount of them. and i think: if you make dua to change past, or to make a miracle, you can be not very happy after that happens, and you get what you want only with that, because, that means that in the normal worlds, without miracles, you probably could not reach what you want, and that is more real.

Comment: that could be effect of brain trauma...

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can make dua for the past. Below is the evidence:

Allah's messenger(ﷺ) used to recite below dua while prostrating (Sujood) which indicates forgiveness of past and future sins.

> اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبِي كُلَّهُ، دِقَّهُ وَجِلَّهُ، وَأَوَّلَهُ
> وَآخِرَهُ وَعَلَانِيَّتَهُ وَسِرَّهُ
>
> O Allah, forgive me all my sins, great and small, the **first** and
> the **last**, those that are apparent and those that are hidden.
>
> Muslim 1/350

Here is another one he(ﷺ) used to recite in tashahhud & before end of the prayer:

> اللّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لي ما قَدَّمْتُ وَما أَخَّرْت ، وَما أَسْرَرْتُ وَما
> أَعْلَنْت ، وَما أَسْرَفْت ، وَما أَنْتَ أَعْلَمُ بِهِ مِنِّي. أَنْتَ
> المُقَدِّمُ، وَأَنْتَ المُؤَخِّرُ لا إِلهَ إِلاّ أَنْت
>
> O Allah, forgive me for **what I have sent before me** and **what I
> have left behind me**, what I have concealed and what I have done
> openly, what I have done in excess, and what You are better aware of
> than I. You are the One Who sends forth and You are the One Who
> delays. There is none worthy of worship but You.
>
> Muslim 1/534