# What is source the of this hadith? (nawawi, ... what has befallen you was not going to pass you by ... )

Tags: hadith, source-identification

http://sunnah.com/nawawi40/19

> On the authority of Abu Abbas Abdullah bin Abbas (may Allah be pleased
>   with him) who said: One day I was behind the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allah be upon him) [riding on the same mount] and he
>   said, “O young man, I shall teach you some words [of advice]: Be
>   mindful of Allah and Allah will protect you. Be mindful of Allah and
>   you .... ” It was related by at-Tirmidhi, who said it was a good and
>   sound hadeeth.
>
> Another narration, other than that of Tirmidhi, reads:
>
> Be mindful of Allah, and you will find Him in front of you,
>
> Recognize and acknowledge Allah in times of ease and prosperity,
>
> And He will remember you in times of adversity,
>
> And know that what has passed you
>   by [and you have failed to attain] was not going to befall you,
>
> And what has befallen you was not going to pass you by,
>
> And know that victory comes with patience,
>
> Relief with affliction, and hardship with ease.

where from is the last hadith?

Comment: I guess you are looking for the source of the narration which is other than the one of Imam at-Tirmidhi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the source of Version of the hadith which you have quoted in your Question, and which differs a bit from the Version of at-Tirmidhi.

I found a link (in Arabic) which says it's from [Musnad al-Imam Ahmad](http://articles.islamweb.net/media/index.php?page=article&lang=A&id=65681) but an other Link gives more [information](http://www.dorar.net/enc/aqadia/3111)

> رواه   أحمد (1/307) (2804)، والطبراني (11/123) (11243)، والحاكم
>   (3/623) والبيهقي في   ((الاعتقاد)) (147) قال الحاكم: هذا حديث كبير عال
>   من حديث عبد الملك بن عمير عن   ابن عباس رضي الله عنهما إلا أن الشيخين
>   رضي الله عنهما لم يخرجا شهاب بن خراش ولا   القداح في الصحيحين وقد روي
>   الحديث بأسانيد عن ابن عباس غير هذا، وقال البيهقي: له   شواهد عن ابن
>   عباس، وصححه عبدالحق الإشبيلي في ((الأحكام الشرعية الكبرى))   (3/333).

Here my own summarized translation of the quoted text:

According this it was narrated by Imam Ahmad (Hadith #2804), Imam at-Tabarani (Hadith #11243), al-Hakim (in his Mustadrak), al-Bayhaqi in al I'tiqad (#147) both al-Hakim and al-Bayhaqi said it's according to the conditions of the two sahih Books but not quoted in them. Abdul-haqq al-Ishbyli has qualified it as sahih in his book al-Ahkam ash-shar'aya al-Kubra! Besides this hadith has a high sanad (this means a short narrator chain as al-Hakim added).

And Allah knows best!